# make two dispatch() run concurrently in directx12

Tags: memory-barriers, directx-12

the problem:

```
there is only one [Buffer]
only compute shaders are used
there is [DispatchA] and [DispatchB]
[DispatchA] reads and writes to [Buffer]
[DispatchB] reads and writes to [Buffer]
[DispatchA] and [DispatchB] reads and writes do not collide
[DispatchA] will run 1 time
[DispatchB] will run 2 times, the second time only after the first time finished
make [DispatchA] and [DispatchB] run at the same time on the GPU
```

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/executing-and-synchronizing-command-lists) says that a resource can't be written by two command queues
so `DispatchA` and `DispatchB` need to be on the same command list
one `UAVbarrier` would be needed between the two `DispatchB`
but `UAVbarrier` will make the second `DispatchB` wait for `DispatchA` to finish
so is it possible to make `DispatchA` and `DispatchB` run completely asynchronous?

Comment: For general advice on DirectX 12, you should look at the [DirectX Discord Channel](https://discord.com/invite/directx)

Answer (score 0):

I asked on the official directx discord
looks like directx12 can't do but CUDA can
so I am now using CUDA as compute and directx12 renders to the screen